# how to iterate over all drawable of another APK's resources without knowing their resources name

Tags: android

I couldn't find how to list all drawable inside another app from my app.

I managed to get drawables if I know the name, but couldn't find how to do it with a simple loop from 1 to N.

Any of you could offer a code template to do this?

The following code already works:

```
mAndromedaAddonContext = createPackageContext( "com.demo.andromeda",
                Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY );
mPlanetsResID[0] = mAndromedaAddonResources.getIdentifier( "planet20111007081421628", "drawable", "com.demo.andromeda" );
```

But I want to iterate without using the resource name.
Something along those lines:
    for(int i=0; i

I do have the same sharedUserId and process in the manifest file, so I have the privilege to access the resources from the other app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `mAndromedaAddonResources.getAssets()` to get an instance of AssetManger for the app you are targeting.

see here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets()

Then you can use the

`public final String[] list (String path)`

method in AssetManager class to get a  list of all assets at a given path( In your case, it would be the path of the res/drawable folder for the app you are targeting). This will give you a list of strings where each string is an asset name. Then you can simply use the same code you are using to obtain their identifiers.

For more info on AssetManager:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Comment: Fantastic! Been stuck on this for a while now. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, can you give me specific example. I'm not able to get res/drawable folder with your way.